# Prove that given graph isn't Hamiltonian

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonicity

I'm facing the problem of proving that given graph IS NOT Hamiltonian.
As far as I know, both Ore's and Dirac's theorem do not work in opposite direction. Therefore I'm left with another "hint" given on lecture, stating:

- If $G\setminus S$ yields more than $|S|$ components, it is not Hamiltonian.

I haven't found any such subset. I've seen solutions to such problems, however containing a bridge, which isn't the case here. I do also know that obviously from every vertex of degree $2$ both of its edges must be used. However I do not know how to use this knowledge here. Could you show me how to use the tools I have or which way to follow here?

[image]

EDIT 1: If we start constructing given graph from the outer circle, without adding any inner edges or vertex K, we have a graph that is Hamiltonian. In this case, adding any edge doesn't change its state. Adding a vertex of even degree, with its edges connected to non-adjacent outer edges (for example here K connected with B and E, not B and A) seems to make it non-Hamiltonian. Although it seems to also work here, I can't figure out a formal explanation.

PS. Thank you Brian for editing.

Comment: What graph do you mean, the one in the picture? Or any graph which has all vertices of degree 3?

Comment: The one added. Seems like the title isn't exactly concrete, but misleading instead. I will change that.

Comment: Is $S$ a vertex set or an edge set? Or is it both (so you delete a vertex with its edges)?

Comment: S is a vertex set. Of course deleting it deletes also adjacent edges.

Comment: Well, a simple remark is that the graph without the middle vertex is Hamiltonian. So whatever you do you don't want to delete that.

Comment: One way to use your knowledge about degree 2 vertices is to replace them with edges.  $A \mapsto \{B,J\}$ and $F \mapsto \{E,H\}$.  This leaves eight vertices from which you want to delete at most three vertices yielding four or more connected components...

Comment: There is no such $S$ for this graph, so you need to use a different criterion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Petersen graph is well-known to be non-Hamiltonian. This graph is a spanning subgraph of the Petersen graph obtained by edge deletion. Thus it is non-Hamiltonian.
[image]

Comment: The peterson graph is connected and not a tree, and therefore contains a cycle.  Are you implying that such a cycle which is a proper subgraph of the peterson graph is non-hamiltonion?

Comment: This graph is obtained from the Petersen graph by deleting only edges, so if the Petersen graph is not Hamiltonian, then this graph isn't Hamiltonian.

Comment: @D.Thomine Now that is a good and correct argument.  Now if Laars would correct his post I could remove the downvote, because as worded it is incorrect.  A proper subgraph obtained only by deleting edges is a very different concept than simply a proper subgraph.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I agree, that's why I'm waiting before I can upvote this answer. I just found useful to point the correct version of the argument.

Comment: Fixed. I was trying to draw a picture and get it added to this post. I should have taken more time to read what I posted.

Comment: @Mr_Max To embellish on Laars' proof, he approaches via contradiction.  Suppose that your graph *did* in fact have a hamiltonian path.  Then that same path could be used for the peterson graph (*since adding only certain edges transforms your graph into the peterson graph*), however since we know the petersongraph is nonhamiltonian this is an impossibility.  My first comment points out that the phrasing was imprecise since cycles obviously are hamiltonian and there is a cycle as a proper subgraph of the peterson graph.

Comment: I believe you mean Hamiltonian cycle @JMoravitz? I'm always split with arguments based on "known facts" since if you do not know about it, you obviously will not see it and draw an argument from that. However after that it seems very usefull and correct. Thank you for restating the way of thinking!